# An error occured submitting the edit - SQL

Tags: sql, post

I am getting errors trying the answer a question and posting a SQL query.

The unhelpful error message is:
An error occured submitting the edit

Here is what I tried to submit:

```
select empname, phone, email 
from employee
where emptype = 'PT' 
and salary between 30000 and 50000
order by city, faculty, empid;
```

Why could I post it here?
I did mark it as code {} (the 4 space indent).

Comment: You can post anything as code here. It's just formatting to make it look different than normal text. As for your error, what is giving you the error message? What are you using to query the database?

Comment: Questions about site errors belong on meta. Try reading the help pages first, though, they may contain an answer.

Comment: @Lebowski156 It seems like this is an issue trying to post the code on SO, not actually run the query.

Comment: I have read the relevant help pages and done that it said.  However, it just told me to mark it as code.  Is there a specific section I may be overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error was actually caused in the text I used to describe the query.  I had the phrase 'select list' but when I reworded that it work.  But that phrase works here - strange.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a type to ORDER BY either ASC or DESC

```
ORDER BY column1, column2, ... ASC|DESC;
```

[Go to W3S](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)